# Building error c101008d Visual Studio c++ related to mt.exe

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++-2008

I need to compile a code in C++ which has some OpenCV functions and does a kind of test. The fact is that the code has worked in other computers, I just need to set the includes and libraries properly to make it work on my PC.

I get this strange error in release mode when building.

```
Error: general error c101008d: Failed to write the updated manifest to the resource of file ".\bin\pcTest.exe". The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. mt.exe
```

I found other answers that say mt.exe has to do with the antivirus, or something like that. Anybody knows why is this happening or how can I solve it?

Comment: `mt.exe` is an application included with the SDK that embeds a manifest into an application. It's not an antivirus application. But *yours* might be interfering: have you configured it with an exclusion for your Visual Studio install directory (and subdirectories) and your code project directories?

Comment: Well, the administrator of the company configured it, so I need to check it, but the fact is that I didn't copied this project inside my usual project folder but on desktop. I will try to put it inside the VStudio project folder.

Comment: Anti-malware is 99.99% the reason of this error.  Avast is particularly incompatible with VS.  Symantec Endpoint has a high suck factor too but is much less consistent in screwing up your build.  The other 0.01% is an actual virus trying to mess with the .exe that was just created :)  A workaround is to mess with the msbuild .targets file and insert a delay before mt.exe, something you really don't want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the .exe file there when you look for it? If so, check whether something else is locking it using LockHunter (http://lockhunter.com). The only time I've had this error is when I've already been running the program and then tried to build it again -- make sure that's not what's happening :)

Answer (score 1):

I get this error when I try to output the debug version of an executable into a directory that exists in my `C:/Program Files (x86)` directory. This is a Visual Studio project property I set. (Right click project | Properties | General | Output Directory).

I fixed this issue by **temporarily disabling Symantec Endpoint Protection**. If your privs don't allow you to do that, you can try outputting the executable somewhere else then copy/pasting it into the desired directory.